# Is there a Hindu cult in India that drink cow urine to cure diseases?

Tags: india, hinduism

[Dailymail.co.uk](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2538520/Urine-drinking-Hindu-cult-believes-warm-cup-sunrise-straight-virgin-cow-heals-cancer-followers-queuing-try-it.html) claims that

> A growing cult of Hindu worshippers in India claim that drinking fresh cow urine will help cure them of all diseases ...

[This](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/weird-news/hindu-worshippers-drink-cow-urine-3017661)  report by Mirror.co.uk says:

> Many say the recent increase in the number of people drinking cow urine can be attributed to campaigns run by spiritual leaders.
>
> Followers of the cult claim cow urine can successful be used to cancer, diabetes, tumours, tuberculosis, stomach problems and much more.

The second report sounds more reliable. Is the claim in the first report that "A growing cult of Hindu worshippers in India claim that drinking fresh cow urine will help cure them of all diseases ..." true?

Or, is it an exaggeration of the second report?

Comment: Downvoters, may I know what's wrong with this post? Your feedback will help me improve it.

Comment: @DavePhD You misunderstood. I am not asking whether cow urine helps cure diseases. I am asking whether some Hindu worshippers claim that or not. I tried to make it as clear as I could.

Comment: related : http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34370/does-cow-urine-contain-gold

Comment: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/does-drinking-the-urine-of-camels-have-medical-benefits?s=1|1.3051

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Cow urine is considered a best remedy for all diseases in Ayurveda.

[INNOVATIVE NATUROPATHY COW URINE AND HERBAL EXTRACTS: A TRAILBLAZER REMEDY](https://books.google.com/books?id=h9-4CgAAQBAJ&pg=PP4&dq=%22cow%20urine%22%20%22all%20diseases%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKqITrnPTQAhVEQZAKHQpqBb0Q6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22cow%20urine%22%20%22all%20diseases%22&f=false)
By Dr. Farida P. Minocheherhomji

[Ayurveda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayurveda) is an aspect of Hinduism.

The book explains that cow urine is significant in Hinduism, Jainism and Zoroastrianism.

See also [The Materia Medica of the Hindus: Compiled from Sanskrit Medical Works](https://books.google.com/books?id=aOcnAAAAYAAJ&pg=PR6&dq=Ayurveda&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj77t70pvTQAhXEHJAKHd0gBL8Q6AEIJTAC#v=onepage&q=urine&f=false), 1877:

> The properties of the urine of various animals, such as the cow, buffalo, goat, sheep, horse, elephant, ass, and camel are minutely described. Of these cow's urine is much used both internally and externally

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin "Ayurveda" refers to a subset of Hinduism.  And the claim doesn't say "many", it says an increasing number.

Comment: ""Ayurveda" refers to a subset of Hinduism." Explain that and update your answer.

Comment: @DavePhD I've corrected the question as, in fact, "many" was not claimed at all.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/4592608/India-makes-cola-from-cow-urine.html

> RSS's Cow Protection Department has invented a new urine-based soft drink it hopes will promote its health-giving properties to a wider market. "We refer to gau ark (cow urine) as gau jal (cow water) as it has immense potential to cure various diseases. We have developed a soft drink formula with gau jal as the base and it has been sent to a laboratory at Lucknow for testing," said director Om Prakash.